# Is an xml sitemap good or bad

Tags: search-engines, sitemap, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any clear indicators that my sitemap file is beneficial?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30186/are-there-any-clear-indicators-that-my-sitemap-file-is-beneficial)

The good:

- You provide search engines with all the urls in your site

But, does the search engine search further than the provided urls in the xml site map?
If you have a website with a forum does every post need to be in the sitemap?

What if remove the sitemap afterwords, will the search engine need to start over?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a video of Matt Cutts from Google talking about both HTML and XML sitemaps

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi5DGOu1uA0

He suggests starting with an HTML, but if you have time use an XML sitemap as well. HTML sitemaps contain `<a>` tag links something Google will definitely crawl. XML isn't guaranteed but he does say use both if you can