# Structure URLs for multi language SEO

Tags: seo, multilingual, angular.js

I'm making a site targeting Japanese market. Since it's in Japan, the main language is Japanese but I also added the English version.

There are 2 ways of structuring the URLs like this:

1st way

- The root URL will be in Japanese `example.com/`
- The English version will be `example.com/en/`

2nd way

- The root URL will be in Japanese suffixed with `ja` (example.com/ja/)
- The English version is suffixed with `en` (example.com/en/)

One claimed that the 1st way is better since the site will show up in Japanese in Google result.

I did some research and people said the 2nd way is better.

Is there any proven practice on this?

Comment: perhpas this will help you a little: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86882/multi-language-site-landing-page?rq=1